# How to format number in "English" numerals only?

Tags: android, kotlin, numbers

The code `"%.2f".format(1.221)` returns `۱,۲۲` instead of `1.22` on Persian/Arabic/Urdu language devices. How can I make it return always "English" numerals?

I tried `"%.2f".format(1.221, Locale.ENGLISH)` but it still does not work.

Comment: The arguments in Java are `String.format(locale, formatString, values....)`.  I'm not sure about what you're using, but I'd guess the locale in that position looks like just another value for the format.

Comment: @user16320675 it's in kotlin code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea but applying it incorrectly. You indeed simply update the locale. One way is to use the `Formatter` class:

```java
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Locale;

void main() {
  var fmt = new Formatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
  System.out.println(fmt.format("%.2f", 1.221));
}
```

UPDATE: I missed some overloads; `PrintStream`'s `printf` has a Locale variant, as does `String.format`. Thus, this would also work:

```java
import java.util.Locale;

void main() {
  System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f\n", 1.221);
  String example = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f\n", 1.221);
}
```

Comment: Why won't `String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", 1.221)` do the job?

Comment: I've missed those overloads. Edited the answer so they are now mentioned. Good eyes, you two.